# How to clear cin buffer after reading char

Tags: c++, linux, unix, stream, istream

I have one problem. Firstly I need to read one character from user input after that I need to read integer. The problem is that if I enter more than one char on first cin, it doesn't request to enter integer value.
Here is snippet of my code.
Is there any function to reset or clear buffer of cin.
I am newbie, sorry if the question is stupid.  Thanks.

```
int *i = new int;
int *c = new char;
std::cin >> *c;
std::cin >> *i;
```

Comment: It's ok to be a newbie. However, I ___strongly___ recommend you to get a book. And forget about `new`, at least for another month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked:

> Is there any function to reset or clear buffer of cin.

There is [`std::istream::ignore()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore). There is example code at the given link which shows how to use the function.

In your case, I see something like:

```
int i;
int c;
std::cin >> c;
std::cin >> i;

if (std::cin.bad()) {
   std::cin.clear(); // unset failbit
   std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); // skip bad input
   std::cin >> i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those extremely simple problems that no one knows how to do properly it seems. The most effective and efficient way to do this is to call ignore with the exact number of characters in the input buffer.

```
cin.clear();                              //clear errors/bad flags on cin

cin.ignore(cin.rdbuf()->in_avail(), '\n');//precise amount of ignoring
cin.rdbuf()->in_avail() //returns the exact number of characters in the cin buffer.
```

This is the best answer for a few reasons:

No clunky includes.
No giant number processing.
Required operations closer to the input buffer (`in_avail` vs. `numeric_limits`).
Consistency in following input operations (won't read past the "delimiter (`\n`)", or leave characters in the buffer).
Recommended by a c++ language lawyer, Dr Robert Johnson.

Comment: Thank you for the edit Mr. Erickson. New to forums, not new to coding, in any case thank you again.

Comment: This would be very neat if it worked 'as expected', but as: `in_avail` is implemented in many std libraries, it will just return `0`, which is apparently still a conforming implementation.

Comment: The reason is because rdbuff() is a method to access the streambuf* member of  cin  which is a  istream object.  You havent read anything in yet so in_avail()  returns zero when you call it.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure why you are creating pointers here. I also don't know how you aren't getting compiler errors for trying to allocate a `char` for an `int*`. If you need to read in an int and char do the following:

```
int i;
char c;

std::cin >> i;
std::cin >> c;
```

Like Zeta recommended in the comments, sounds like you might need to do a little reading on C++. Hope this helps.